# roman to integer leetcode easy encountering issues

Tags: javascript

This is what I have got but idk where I'm going wrong - I only started coding 3 weeks ago

```js
const roman = {
  "I": 1,
  "V": 5,
  "X": 10,
  "L": 50,
  "C": 100,
  "D": 500,
  "M": 1000
}

function romanToInt(s) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (roman[s[i + 1]] > roman[s[i]]) {
      let prev = (roman[s[i + 1]] - roman[s[i]]);
      sum += prev;
    } else {
      if (i != s.length) {
        sum += roman[s[i]]
      }
    }
  }
  return sum
}

console.log(romanToInt("MMXXII")); // 2022 is correct
console.log(romanToInt("IV"));     // 9 instead of 4
```

Comment: it doesnt work for roman numerals that have a letter in front of it that is larger than the one before it - example: IV

Comment: It's not really doing what it's intending though given an input of "IV" will produce "9" as an output.

Comment: I think what you missed is to increment the `i` inside the `if` block because you don't want to add the extra V from IV.

Comment: LEGEND! tyssmmm :)))

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that in the final iteration of your loop you end up comparing the final element to undefined, so it will always trigger your else statement and always add the final element to the total.

e.g. for "IV" your first loop correct creates the sum as 4, then your second loop enters the else and adds 5 to it. You can fix by not entering your final else if your if condition has been triggered.

```js
const roman = {
  "I": 1,
  "V": 5,
  "X": 10,
  "L": 50,
  "C": 100,
  "D": 500,
  "M": 1000
}

function romanToInt(s) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (roman[s[i + 1]] > roman[s[i]]) {
      let prev = (roman[s[i + 1]] - roman[s[i]]);
      sum += prev;
      i++;
    } else {
      if (i != s.length) {
        sum += roman[s[i]]
      }
    }
  }
  return sum
}


console.log(romanToInt("MMXXII")); // 2022 is correct
console.log(romanToInt("IV")); // 9 instead of 4
```